# Parsing dates from string - regex

Tags: regex, parsing, date, expression

I'm terible with regex and I can't seem to wrap my head around this simple task.

I need to parse out the two dates in a string which always has one of two formats:

"Inquiry at your property for December 29, 2013 - January 03, 2014"

OR

"Inquiry at your property for 29 December , 2013 - 03 January, 2014"

the 2 different date formats are throwing me off. Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(\d+ \w+, \d+|\w+ \d+, \d+)/` for example. Try it out on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/K4rZwH2ssm).

For sure, it would pickup more stuff, like `2013 NotReallyAMonth, 12345`. But if you don't have things in the input that look like a date, but not actually a date this might work.

You could make the regexp stronger, but applying more restrictions on what is matched:

```
/(\d{2} (?:January|December), \d{4}|(?:January|December) \d{2}, \d{4})/
```

In this case the day is always two digits, the year is 4. Months are listed explicitly (you would have to list all of them).

**Update:** For ranges it would be a different regexp:

```
/((?:Jan|Dec) \d+ - \d+, \d{4})/
```

Obviously they can all be [combined together](http://rubular.com/r/8fOrRAcE9J):

```
/(\d{2} (?:January|December), \d{4}|(?:January|December) \d{2}, \d{4}|(?:Jan|Dec) \d+ - \d+, \d{4})/
```

Comment: You don't really need the groups, the way you've written the first one.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP wants to extract the dates, then groups are needed.

Comment: Not in the first one, the first one will only match everything before the alternation, or everything after it, making the groupings redundant.

Comment: Grouping is also needed to apply `|` operator. I'll change groups to `?:`.

Comment: The groupings are absolutely not needed to apply alternation.  Alternation has highest precedence.  http://rubular.com/r/IVurV43Sux

Comment: Thank you for your example! Never knew about Rubular, it makes a great teaching tool, very intuitive. One more variation I would like to add is this: "Inquiry at property for Dec 3 - 8, 2013". How would that be done?

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. I was over-thinking it.